# Is ctype.h installed in my system?

Tags: gcc, c, gdb

I am running 16.04. My C program uses isdigit(int). I get the following when I run it under gdb:

```
`Breakpoint 1, check_tok (token=0x6f7c20 <tokens> ".t") at outline.c:150
150 unsigned char *tp=token;
(gdb) s
151     if(isdigit(*tp))return NUM;
(gdb) 
__ctype_b_loc () at ../include/ctype.h:38
38  ../include/ctype.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

I have already performed :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

`
I do not get any warnings when I run gcc on outline.c. at the top of my program I have:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "outline.h"
```

I only get the above error while in gdb.

What is going on? Thank you.

Comment: Run `locate ctype.h` . It should show up

Answer (score 2):

The problem in not that you don't have ctype.h because you need it to compile your program. In your case it depends on the way gdb is locating includes. Maybe you need to use "locate ctype.h" and set inside gdb the include-directory like:

```
set substitute-path /usr/src/include /mnt/include
```

please have a look here:https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html